# Call function on close of ngDialog

Tags: angularjs

I open an alert dialog with ok button. On click calls a function. I need to call the same function when I close the alert dialog

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="alertErrorTemplate.html">
    <div class="form-wrp">
        <div class="form-item">
            <h2 class="box-title error-text" ng-class="{'box-left': leftAlign}"><span data-ng-bind="Web_Error" ng-show="showTitleText">Error: </span>{{alertText}}</h2>
            <h2 class="box-text error-text" ng-class="{'box-left': leftAlign}" ng-show="secondaryText !== null">{{secondaryText}}</h2>
            <div ng-show="alertItemList && alertItemList.length > 0" class="dialog-error-list error-text">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in alertItemList">
                        {{ item }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item text-center">
            <button ng-click="closeNgDialog()" class="btn btn-success btn-big" data-ng-bind="Web_OK">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I am trying to close the dialog with X in the top of the dialog

Comment: Sajee: Need to call "closeNgDialog()" if I use X to close the dialog not sure where to use that

Comment: Show us the code of `$scope.closeNgDialog()`

Comment: $scope.closeNgDialog = function() {
                            closeNgDialogBase();
                        };

Comment: @Jay Try [this](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#scopeclosethisdialogvalue)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to 'ngDialog.closing' event like this :

```
$scope.$on('ngDialog.closing', function () {
    //do what ever you want.
});
```